# Prove or disprove if two continuous functions are equal when they agree in a dense set.

Tags: general-topology, continuity, examples-counterexamples, separation-axioms, nets

So [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543962/f-g-continuous-from-x-to-y-if-they-are-agree-on-a-dense-set-a-of-x-th) is proved that two continuous functions $f:X\to Y$ and $g:X\to Y$ from a space $X$ to an **hausdorff** space $Y$ are equal when they agree in a dense set $D$ of $X$. However it seem to me that the result could hold also when $Y$ is **not** hausdorff as the following argumentations seem to show.

> So if $x\in X\setminus D$ then $x\in\operatorname{cl}D$ and so that it is the limit of a net $(x_\lambda)_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ in $D$ and thus by continuity we conclude that
> $$
> f(x)=\lim_{\lambda\in\Lambda}f(x_\lambda)=\lim_{\lambda\in\Lambda}g(x_\lambda)=g(x)
> $$
> so that we finally conclude that $f$ and $g$ are equal.

So clearly in the above argumentations I do not use hausdorff-separability but only [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360419/f-brings-convergent-nets-to-convergent-nets-is-it-continuous) relevant result which does not require that $Y$ is hausdorff: however I well know that if $Y$ is not Hausdorff then the limit of $f(x_\lambda)$ and $g(x_\lambda)$ are not generally unique and I realise that this could be a problem but unfortunately I was not able to find a **counterexamle** showing that the result could not hold when $Y$ is **not** an hausdoff space and thus I thought to put a specific queston. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: If $Y$ has the indiscrete topology, then *any* function $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous. By this, it is easy to find counter-examples.

Comment: @Ulli Sorry, I do not see this. So if $Y$ has the indiscrete topology then $f(x_\lambda)$ and $g(x_\lambda)$ converge to any $y\in Y$, right?

Comment: Yes. For instance, let $X = Y$ be a set with more than one point with the indiscrete topology. Consider two functions $f, g: X \rightarrow Y$, which agree on one point, but differ on another point. Or, to have a non-trivial $X$, let $X$ be the reals with the usual topology, $Y$ the reals with the indiscrete topology, and modify the identity at one point.

Comment: @Ulli Sorry, but if $X=Y$ and if $Y$ has the indiscrete topology then the only dense set of $X$ is exactly $X$, right?

Comment: If $X$ has the indiscrete topology, *any* non-empty subset of $X$ is dense in $X$.

Comment: @Ulli Sorry, but if $X$ has the indiscrete topology then any subset of $X$ is closed if the indiscrete topology is just the power set of $X$. Perhaps with the indiscrete topology you want refer to the topology whose open sets are $X$ and the empty set?

Comment: No, it's not me who want to refer to this definition of indiscrete topology. It's the usual definition. Therefore it's called *in...*

Comment: The power set topology is the *discrete* topology!

Comment: @Ulli Okay, so in this case effectively any subset of $X$ is dense.

Comment: @Ulli So could you explain why if $f$ and $g$ agree in one point then they not necessarily agree to other points?

Comment: In my above, first, example you should *choose* $f, g$ in such a way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $X=(\Bbb{R}, \tau_{std}) $ and $ Y=(\Bbb{R},\tau_{ind})$

$\tau_{ind}=\{\emptyset,\Bbb{R}\}$

Consider $f,g: X\to Y$ defined by

$f(x) =1 $ and $g(x) =\begin{cases}1 &x\in \Bbb{Q} \\0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

Then  $f, g$ both are continuous ( as only open sets in $Y$ are $\emptyset$ and $\Bbb{R}$ )and $f=g $ on $\Bbb{Q}$ but $f\neq g$

Comment: Okay, all clear now: answer upvoted and approved. Thanks very much for the counterexample!!!