# Give an example of a function $f :X \to Y$ which is sequential continuous but not continuous where $X$ and $Y$ are some topological spaces.

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Give an example of a function  $f :X \to Y$  which is sequential continuous but not continuous where $X$ and $Y$ are some topological spaces.

I have  seen some example which uses $X$ to be non sequential space but I'm interested in an algebraic example. (I mean in which space $X$ is some algebraic object like ring with Zariski topology or any other topology)

Comment: The example I've seen is taking $X = \omega_1 + 1$ where $\omega_1$ is the first uncountable [ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number) and $Y = \Bbb R$. You then set $$f(\alpha) = \cases{0 & if $\alpha < \omega_1$\\ 1 & if $\alpha = \omega_1$}$$This is a sequentially continuous function, but not a continuous one, if $X$ is endowed with the order topology and $Y$ with the standard one.

Comment: I will add a few links to other post on this site which have examples of such functions: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/351987, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/745036 and perhaps also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53236 (this is a slightly different question).

Comment: Could you be more specific what you mean by *algebraic example*. The current wording of the question might lead to the impression that you only allow Zariski topology for $X$. (In which case the question can be solved by finding an example of a ring for which the Zariski topology is not [sequential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space).

Comment: Some remarks about the general approach to this kind of problems: Once you found a space $X$ which is not sequential, this means precisely that there is some map $f:X\to Y$ such that $f$ is sequentially continuous but not continuous. But finding the space $Y$ and the map $f$ is not even a problem, as you can simply take $f=\text{id}:X\to sX$, where $s$ is the *sequentiallization* of $X$, i.e. the set $X$ equipped with the topology consisting of all sequentially open subsets of $X$.

Comment: In fact, this sequentially continuous map $X\to sX$ is universal from $X$ to the inclusion functor of sequential spaces into the category of all spaces with sequential maps as arrows. So in the end, the problem boils down to finding a non-sequential space.

Comment: @StefanHamcke Thank you.Regards,

Comment: @MartinSleziak I'm unable in finding a ring for which Zariski topology works here?How do you find this ring?[Actually I don't have much idea about  topologies (except Zariski Topology  on Ring)on algebraic objects like Groups,rings,Vector Spaces etc...Can you say some lines about these topologies?]Best Regards,

Comment: @ArpitKansal I am not very familiar with the Zariski topology. However answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53852/is-there-a-way-of-working-with-the-zariski-topology-in-terms-of-convergence-limi) make me believe that working with sequences in Zariski topology will not be very easy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looking for example of topological spaces where sequential continuity does not imply continuity](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1419938/looking-for-example-of-topological-spaces-where-sequential-continuity-does-not-i)