# Constructing a sequence that converges to an accumulation point of a set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

My question is about characterizing accumulation points in terms of convergent sequences in a set $X$. I take the following definition of an accumulation point:

- A point $x_0$ is an accumulation point of a set $X$ if all neighborhoods of $x_0$ contain an infinite points of $X$.

Consider the following assertion: $x_0$ is an accumulation point of $X$ if and only if there is a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ in $X$ with $x_n \rightarrow x_0$ and $x_n \neq x_0$ for $n=1,2,...$

**Proof:** Take $\epsilon_1=1$. The existence of a point $x_1 \in X$ with $0<|x_1-x_0|<\epsilon_1=1$ is guaranteed. Now take $\epsilon_2=|x_1-x_0|/2$ and choose an $x_2 \in X$ with $0<|x_2-x_0|< \epsilon_2$. In general, choose $x_n \in X$ that satisfies $0<|x_n-x_0|< \epsilon_n=\frac{|x_1-x_0|}{2^n}<\frac 1{2^n}$. It is clear that $x_n \rightarrow x_0$ and $x_n \neq x_0$ for $n=1,2,...$

**Question:** Is this correct?

Comment: Are we looking at real numbers? In general we have no norm, "$|\cdot|$", on a topological space.

Comment: I should have mentioned this. Yes we are looking at real numbers.

Comment: Then it is correct!

Comment: @Iconoclast: Sorry then for confusing you with so general stuff - confused myself by the tag [general-topology]

Comment: According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point#Types_of_limit_points) this is the definition of $\omega$-accumulation point. However, for real numbers the two definitions coincide, so there is no problem here.

Comment: @Gortaur: No problem. On the contrary it was informative. I guess the tag i chose was a bit misleading.

Comment: @Iconoclast: that's nice. I would just advise you to put also a tag  [real-analysis] for people not to be confused. Since my answer is somewhat general, [general-topology] is also worth to leave - but that's up to you, just in the case you agree.

Comment: @Iconoclast: Could you also edit the question to explicitly say that $X$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the space is metric or metrizable then your proof is correct. It also proves the equivalent statement:

> A point $x_0$ is an accumulation point of a set $X$ if all neighborhoods of $x_0$ contain at least one point from $X$ other than $x_0$.

On the other hand, you cannot use the same argument for the arbitrary topological space. Clearly, existence of convergence sequence ensures that the point is an accumulation point.

For the first countable spaces you can apply this argument: consider nested neighborhood basis at $x_0$ which we denote $V_1,...,V_n,...$ and pick up any $x'_i\in V_i$, then $\lim\limits_{i\to\infty}x'_i = x_0$ since in neighborhood $U$ of $x_0$ contain all $V_i$ starting with some $i$.

Nested neighborhood basis $(V_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ is a neighborhood basis such that $V_{i+1}\subseteq V_i$. You can construct from the usual basis $B_1,...,B_n,...$ by taking $V_i = \bigcap\limits_{j=1}^i B_j$.

Unfortunately I cannot tell you if there exists a convergent sequence to an accumulation point for the spaces which are not first countable.

Comment: You asked, whether there are spaces which are not first countable and still have this property. Yes, they are such spaces. You can learn about them if you search for Frechet-Urysohn spaces, see e.g. this answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49110/sequence-lemma-relaxing-some-hypothesis-of-a-theorem

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Thank you very much